# Access Synology NAS from outside. Ports forwarded, just don't know how to set up

Tags: port-forwarding, synology-diskstation

Being behind several routers, I needed to rely only on Quickconnect from Synology.

Now I've managed to get ports forwarded to me from ISP, so I've got 21, 80, 5000, 5001 ports opened. They also gave me some IP address, probably it's external IP of whole their network.

Problem is, that Synology 120j doesn't allow me to set this up manualy (or maybe I don't know how) rather than forcing me to go trought wizard which keeps complaining about the routers not being in "bridge mode".

When I look on internet, there are several videos, but all of them use old Synology menu where is "Port forwarding" option located.
Now I'm going via Control Panel > External Access > Router Configuration where I need to first set up router and than I can get to setting up the ports.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Have you tried to continue with the wizard despite the warning about multiple routers?

Comment: sure I've got to the page, where system is testing UPnP compatibility and I've got red cross on "Add port forwarding rules". In previous step I've choosed Quick option (since I don't have log in's for the router). All I know that ISP has already opened ports for me

Comment: @JZK If it's behind several routers, are you double/triple NAT'd? UPnP should never be used, as there is no secure implementation of it, so port redirects should always be manually configured _(port `80` shouldn't be port forwarded to your Synology, as anything requiring a login should only be accessed over HTTPS [port `443`])_. In order for anyone to help troubleshoot, please add to your question the network layout and subnets involved.

Answer (score 0):

so I've find out. Once you have ports opened (I've did in the end 80, 443, 5000 and 5001), you just need to create manualy configuration for a router ,which will not work, but it will let you to go to another step, where you can set up the ports you have opened